# HTML & PHP - Undefined variable: FILES to upload file

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to upload a file using php. I have a form with input type='file' and I choose the file to upload click to send button.

My HTML code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test Form</title>
</head>

<body>

    <form action="test2.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="image1"/>
        <input type="submit" value="send">
    </form>

</body>
```

My PHP code:

```
<?php

  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name'],'assets/images/upload/'.$FILES['image1']['name']);

?>
```

The error in the log file of the apache server is:

*PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: FILES in ...*

Please Could you help me?

Comment: change `$FILES` to `$_FILES`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have typo in your code `$FILES['image1']['name']`

Replace this line

```
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name'],'assets/images/upload/'.$FILES['image1']['name']);
```

with this

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name'],'assets/images/upload/'.$_FILES['image1']['name']);
```

Answer (score 2):

Should be:

```
<?php

  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name'],'assets/images/upload/'.$_FILES['image1']['name']);

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name'],'assets/images/upload/'.$_FILES['image1']['name']);
```

In you **move_uploaded_file** function you have made the mistake ie the 2nd attribute should be **$_FILES** Now you please change this then your error will work. Please have a try.

Answer (score 0):

i think it should be.

```
<?php

  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image1']["tmp_name"],'assets/images/upload/'.$FILES['image1']['name']);

?>
```

tmp_name use as string format.